# How can create fully custom widgets using dart for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can create fully custom widgets using dart programming for flutter
without using any packages

Comment: Definitaly check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61984781/15236786

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom widgets like this-

```
class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      String? selectedOption;
      CustomWidget({ this.selectedOption});
      @override
      _CustomWidgetState createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
    }
    class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
      String? _dropDownValue;
      TextEditingController t1Controller = TextEditingController();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        return Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          child: Container(
            width: _width,
            height: 50,
            child: Widget// Add here your widgets
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```